# Install django-tracking2

Tags: django, python-3.4

I'm trying to use the App Django-Tracking2
From here : https://github.com/bruth/django-tracking2

I'm running on Python 3.4 and Django 1.8.7

So I do pip install django-tracking2 (Successfull)

- I put tracking on INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
- I put 'tracking.middleware.VisitorTrackingMiddleware', on
  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
- And I put url(r'^tracking/', include('tracking.urls')), in my urls.py

Then,

- I launch my virtual env
- I connect to the my Admin Django
- Go to localhost/tracking/

But here I've a problem,
when I go on localhost/tracking/ I have this error :

AttributeError at /tracking/

'Profile' object has no attribute 'has_perms'

Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response

132. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view

21. if test_func(request.user):

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in check_perms

67. if user.has_perms(perms):

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner

226. return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /tracking/

Exception Value: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'has_perms'

If someone can help me it will be very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a custom User model? If so, it must derive from Django's AbstractBaseUser class and use PermissionsMixin.

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions). Django-Tracking2 looks for standard fields/methods of the User model and in this case is not finding them.

Perhaps post where your User model is defined and CUSTOM_AUTH_MODEL in settings (if set) and we can provide more help.

For example, if your `Profile` model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
```

Change to this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, Permissions Mixin

class Profile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

Then, run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` in order to update the database. The needed fields will be present and django-tracking2 will be able to call the fields/methods needed.

Comment: It's ok, I've deleted my databse remake a makemigrations and a migrate and it's work,

Comment: But now I've another question, have you idea how can I overload the template of this app ?

Comment: Your project's TEMPLATE_DIRS setting list a series of folders in which Django attempts to find a match for any template. In addition, the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting specifies what methods Django uses to find templates. I have overridden the dashboard template ofor django-tracking2's dashboard by creating a dir and file (w/ directories) at `tracking/dashboard.html'. Look at the template dir for the track app itself and you'll see that same file. There's a lot to discuss, here's a good post- http://tundebabzy.blogspot.com/2013/04/overriding-templates-from-django-apps.html